# How to resize partition in-between other partitions (CLI)?

Tags: command-line, partition, ext4, parted

How can I resize some partitions on a disk where there are other partitions before and after it?

I've found plenty of guides on the Internet about how to resize a partition (eg with `parted`), but they all just show a disk with a single partition. How can I do this with multiple partitions?

My specific use-case is a cloud-based network disk that can be magically resized from a WUI. For the purposes of this question, let's throw out that complexity and make answers cloud-provider-agnostic. Consider the following commands to setup a simplified example:

```
# create 100 MB "disk" file
head -c 104857600 < /dev/urandom > my_disk
cryptsetup luksFormat my_disk
cryptsetup luksOpen my_disk my_disk

# parition disk with 8M, 4M, 1M, 32M, & 36M partitions
echo "label: dos
label-id: 0x34a96950
device: /dev/mapper/my_disk
unit: sectors
sector-size: 512

/dev/mapper/my_disk-part1 : start=        2048, size=       16384, type=83
/dev/mapper/my_disk-part2 : start=       18432, size=        8192, type=83
/dev/mapper/my_disk-part3 : start=       26624, size=        2048, type=83
/dev/mapper/my_disk-part4 : start=       28672, size=      143360, type=5
/dev/mapper/my_disk-part5 : start=       30720, size=       65536, type=83
/dev/mapper/my_disk-part6 : start=       98304, size=       73728, type=83
" | sfdisk /dev/mapper/my_disk
partprobe /dev/mapper/my_disk

# create ext4 filesystems 
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/my_disk1
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/my_disk2
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/my_disk3
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/my_disk5
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/my_disk6
```

The above commands create a 100 MB "disk" file that's encrypted with LUKS and partitioned into 5 ext4 filesystems of sizes:

1. 8 MB
2. 4 MB
3. 1 MB
4. 32 MB
5. 36 MB

Now let's double the size of the disk

```
head -c 104857600 < /dev/urandom >> my_disk
```

Now that the disk is twice as large, I'd like to resize the disk's partitions as follows:

1. 8 MB -> 10 MB
2. 4 MB -> 5 MB
3. 1 MB -> 16 MB
4. 32 MB -> 29 MB
5. 36 MB -> (rest of space available)

Assuming the second-to-last partition had 10 MB of free space, how can I resize these filesystems (&& LUKS container && partitions) such that there's no data loss? Is there any CLI tools that allow me to do this easily, without having to delete the partition table and input start/end values manually? Ideally I'd like something where I can just type `+2M` to increase a partition's size by 2 MB.

Comment: Since a partition must be contiguous, if the partitions have been originally created with no gaps, then a partition that is not the last on the disk can only grow if all partitions located after it are **moved** further on the disk ("to the right"). Such a move operation requires the partition to be unmounted while being moved, so it's often easiest to do when the system is booted on a Live CD or other alternative bootable media. `gparted` could perform move operations with an easy user interface, but it is not a CLI tool.

Comment: I just tried this in `parted`. I had to manually calculate the end of the partition, and I got `Error: Can't have overlapping partitions`. So does that mean `gparted` not only wraps `parted` but it also quietly wraps `parted` with additional commands to delete partitions after the partition you resize and automatically re-creates them further "to the right"? My server is remote & headless. Is there really no CLI tool that does this?

Comment: You cannot use gparted on volumes, only on partition that contains the volumes. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions  and http://askubuntu.com/questions/262211/how-do-i-resize-an-encrypted-lvm-to-install-another-copy-of-ubuntu & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/663332/what-is-the-proper-way-to-install-ubuntu-15-04-with-lvm-luks-and-manual-partit

Comment: `growpart` (sometimes packaged on its own, sometimes a part of `cloud-utils`) would be a command-line tool that can easily extend a single partition, but it cannot move other partitions. But since you are doubling the size of your disk, this would be a good opportunity to switch from partitions to LVM if you want to. I'll write a more detailed answer about this later this weekend.

Answer (score 2):

(Personally, I think creating multiple partitions of less than 1 GB as "unnecessary micro-managing" these days, with possible exceptions for the EFI System Partition and maybe `/boot`. But I'm sure you have your reasons.)

Since you are *doubling* the existing size of the disk, this would be a good opportunity to transition to LVM.

First make sure your LVM tools are available. If this is your root filesystem, you might have to rebuild your initramfs to get the tools included into it.

After extending the encrypted volume:

```
head -c 104857600 < /dev/urandom >> my_disk
cryptsetup resize my_disk
```

you could create a single new partition that takes up all the added space, using whichever partitioning tool you prefer. It should appear as `/dev/mapper/my_disk-part7`. Set its type to 8e (Linux LVM).

Initialize it for LVM use:

```
pvcreate /dev/mapper/my_disk-part7
```

Create a new LVM volume group (VG for short):

```
vgcreate my_vg /dev/mapper/my_disk-part7
```

Now create LVM logical volumes (LVs for short) to match your existing partitions.

```
lvcreate -L 8M -n my_lv1 my_vg 
lvcreate -L 4M -n my_lv2 my_vg 
lvcreate -L 1M -n my_lv3 my_vg 
lvcreate -L 32M -n my_lv5 my_vg 
lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n my_lv6 my_vg
```

Note: use upper-case `-L` when specifying a size in mega/giga/tera bytes, and lower-case `-l` when specifying percentages of either free or total capacity.

Create filesystems:

```
for i in 1 2 3 5 6; do mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/my_vg-my_lv$i; done
```

You will be able to use the `vgs` command to view how much of the total VG space you have allocated to logical volumes, and `lvs` to show the sizes of the individual logical volumes.

Schedule some application downtime, and copy everything from the old disks to the new ones:

```
mkdir /old /new
mount /dev/mapper/my_disk-part1 /old
mount /dev/mapper/my_vg-my_lv1 /new
cp -a /old/* /new/
umount /new
umount /old
```

... and repeat for all 5 partitions.

Now you can change your `/etc/fstab` entries to refer to the LVM logical volumes instead of the old partitions. If this includes your root filesystem, remember to edit the *new* root filesystem, not the old one. You might also want to create an extra boot option so that you can explicitly choose to boot with either the old or the new root filesystem, and so verify everything gets mounted where they should. Test carefully, **especially** if your root filesystem is included.

Once you are successfully using LVM, it's time to tear down the old setup. Delete the old partitions #1, #2, #3 and create just one partition in their place (to minimize overhead). Set its type to 8e (Linux LVM) too. That will be the new `/dev/mapper/my_disk-part1`. Change the types of partitions #5 and #6 to 8e (Linux LVM).

After this partitioning is complete, you can resume using the system as normal.

Now, initialize the freed partitions for use by LVM:

```
pvcreate /dev/mapper/my_disk-part1
pvcreate /dev/mapper/my_disk-part5
pvcreate /dev/mapper/my_disk-part6
```

Add them to the existing volume group:

```
vgextend my_vg /dev/mapper/my_disk-part1
vgextend my_vg /dev/mapper/my_disk-part5
vgextend my_vg /dev/mapper/my_disk-part6
```

If you run `vgs` at this point, you should see that `my_vg` is now about 200M in size, and about 100M of it. The fact that the free space is now *physically* "to the left" of the existing LVs **does not matter**: you can use it to extend **any** of your LVs as you see fit. And you can do it **while everything is mounted and in use**.

So, you can now do what you originally wanted:

```
lvextend -r -L 10M /dev/mapper/my_vg-my_lv1
lvextend -r -L +1MB /dev/mapper/my_vg-my_lv2
lvextend -r -L +15M /dev/mapper/my_vg-my_lv3
```

Shrinking a mounted `ext4` filesystem is unfortunately not supported:

```
umount /dev/mapper/my_vg-my_lv5
lvreduce -r -L 29M /dev/mapper/my_vg-my_lv5
mount /dev/mapper/my_vg-my_lv5
```

And finally, assign all the remaining unassigned capacity to the last LV:

```
lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/my_vg-my_lv6
```

### For the future:

If you need to increase the size of the disk file again, you can probably do it without booting, while everything is mounted and running:

```
head -c 104857600 < /dev/urandom >> my_disk   # extend disk image
cryptsetup resize my_disk                     # tell the encryption layer to use it
growpart /dev/mapper/my_disk 7                # extend partition
pvresize /dev/mapper/my_disk-part7            # tell the LVM PV to use it
```

... and then you'll have 100MB more to allocate to your LVs using `lvextend` or for creating entirely new LVs with `lvcreate`.

If you need to migrate to an entirely new disk, let me surprise you by telling that you can do that while everything is mounted too:

```
vgextend my_vg /dev/mapper/my_new_disk       # add new disk to the VG
pvmove /dev/mapper/my_disk                   # migrate everything away from the old PV
vgreduce my_vg /dev/mapper/my_disk
```

Then tear down the old disk.

At work, we've migrated an entire datacentre to new storage doing basically just this... several times, every 5 years or so, as the support for old enterprise storage hardware ends/becomes more expensive than switching to new hardware.

Comment: Thanks! `Personally, I think creating multiple partitions of less than 1 GB as "unnecessary micro-managing" these days` Just to clarify, the small partitions in this example were created just for a simplified example for the purposes of this question (to make things faster & easier)